# jQuery/javascript: use PHP return value as javaScript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, get

is there anyway to import a javaScript array from a PHP return value?

Say that a PHP script, 'makeArray.php', would return '"first","second","third"' (without single quotes). The purpose of the below would thus be to alert 'second'.

```
$.get(makeArray.php, function(data){
    var responseArray = new Array(data);
    alert(responseArray[1]);
    ...
```

However all I get is 'undefined'. If I was to change the array index to [0], I would get '"first","second","third"'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, what you are doing is that you are including all the data recieved form the file (`makeArray.php`) into the first element of an array. So, obviously it would be in the zero-index of the array.

What you should do in this case is use `Array.split()` function on the array like - `data.split(",")` to create an array from the data recieved.

Comment: That's a pretty nifty solution. As I can't use JSON (see below) I think this is the only way to go about the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Matte Select my answer as the chosen one if this thing works out for you. I would owe you for this. Thanks for appreciating!

Comment: yeh, yeh, still a few minutes to go before the system lets me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use JSON.

In PHP

```
$myarray = array('first','second','third');
return json_encode($myarray);
```

In JavaScript:

```
$.get(makeArray.php, function(data){
  console.log(data[1]); //=> "second"
}, 'json');
```

**Edit**

If you don't have PHP 5.2 then you can try echoing a string and parsing it in JavaScript:

PHP:

```
echo join('%',$myarray);
```

JS:

```
var array = data.split('%');
```

Comment: +1. You just beat me. Could also use [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getJSON/) instead of `$.get()`.

Comment: That is a great answer for most looking to solve similar issues as mine above, however servers running PHP 5.1.6, so can't implement it...

Comment: Indeed. I think akash4eva already came up with the solution. But thanks, though...

Comment: Check [this comment in the PHP docs for an implementation of json_encode prior to 5.2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#107968)

Comment: Or in this case knowing that you are sending a comma-delimited list of strings just echo an opening `[`, then the values, then a closing `]`. Instant JSON. (Yes, hand-coding JSON is not usually a good plan, but for a simple array with a version of PHP that doesn't have `json_encode()` I don't think it's a problem.)